# Django IntegrityError: Column 'position' cannot be null

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-cms

I'm using Django-CMS and I created some custom plugins that I use in several pages but in one of the pages I can't publish nor I can't copy plugins that are nested and gives me the same error in both situations:

```
Internal Server Error: /en/admin/cms/page/copy-plugins/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 244, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\http.py", line 42, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\clickjacking.py", line 39, in wrapped_view
    resp = view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 184, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\cms\admin\placeholderadmin.py", line 363, in copy_plugins
    plugins, target_placeholder, target_language, target_plugin_id)
  File "lib\site-packages\cms\utils\copy_plugins.py", line 24, in copy_plugins_to
    old_parent_cache, no_signals))
  File "lib\site-packages\cms\models\pluginmodel.py", line 319, in copy_plugin
    new_plugin.save()
  File "lib\site-packages\cms\models\pluginmodel.py", line 240, in save
    self.parent.add_child(instance=self)
  File "lib\site-packages\treebeard\mp_tree.py", line 970, in add_child
    return MP_AddChildHandler(self, **kwargs).process()
  File "lib\site-packages\treebeard\mp_tree.py", line 361, in process
    newobj.save()
  File "lib\site-packages\cms\models\pluginmodel.py", line 248, in save
    super(CMSPlugin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 820, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 859, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1039, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1060, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 117, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'position' cannot be null")
```

I've checked in my database and in the `cms_cmsplugin`table exists a column named `position` but there's no entry with `position null`. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: The `position` column has been defined such that it cannot contain `NULL` values.  Your code attempted to create a row that contained a NULL for that column, thus an exception was raised.

Comment: @JohnGordon But I don't have on my custom plugins any field named position (I've checked). So the `position` must be from the django-cms tables.

Comment: @patricia can you update your question to include djangoCMS and django versions? I believe this issue was fixed on >= 3.3.x

Comment: @Paulo it was indeed a version problem, I had to upgrade my django cms and django versions and then it worked fine.